# Using Quarkus with bare Vertx: Server responds only to one connection

Tags: java, vert.x, quarkus, vertx-verticle

I tried to create a Quarkus App with bare Vertx. However, I can't curl multiple times. Only the first curl give me the correct response.

I tried to use Vertx without Quarkus (main method). Then everything works fine. Each curl gives the correct response. So I think I initialize Vertx wrong when I use Quarkus.

Code: Verticle Deployer

```
package Super.Company.App;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Verticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;

@ApplicationScoped
public class App {
  @Inject
  Vertx vertx;

  public void init(@Observes StartupEvent e, Vertx vertx, Instance<AbstractVerticle> verticles) {
    for (AbstractVerticle verticle : verticles) {
      vertx.deployVerticle(verticle);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    Verticle myVerticle = new MyVerticle();
    vertx.deployVerticle(myVerticle);
  }

}
```

Code: Verticle

```
package Super.Company.App;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerResponse;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start() {
    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();

    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    router.route().handler(routingContext -> {

      // This handler will be called for every request
      HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
      response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");

      // Write to the response and end it
      response.end("Hello World from Vert.x-Web!");
    });

    server.requestHandler(router).listen(8080);
  }
}
```

edit:
I have spammed the curl command and occasionally I got the correct response. Every 16th curl command responds correctly.

update:
Besides the curl spamming, I made some tests. I used [hey](https://github.com/rakyll/hey), Postman, Google Chrome and Safari.

hey: 5% - 15% were a 200 and the rest were a 404.

Postman: I received only 404. But after restarting the server, it responds only 200.

Browsers: Only one tab can connect to the server. I can refresh this tap multiple times and the server sends a 200 each time. I have to restart the server to connect with other tabs. However, if I refresh the other tabs they get a 404.

Comment: Did you read/follow thiese guides ? https://quarkus.io/guides/vertx, https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes

Answer (score 0):

You crrated 2 vertex instance in the same app.

1. Injected one
2. Manually one on the main method

Why does the injected one was not enough?

You deploy verticle to each vertex intances. Where does verticles in the init method come from?

If you are in a quarkus app it will be better to explicitly start the main quarkus method.

The injected vertx instance should be the only one you should use. For you simple case. Try to understand dependency injections in quarkus